# Shape index, compactness and assymetry index with PostgreSQL /PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, vector, geometry

I am working on automated land parcel identification and would like to extract road/river/thin and linear-like polygons from a massive dataset. For now, the only index I can get some answers from is the ratio between the perimeter and the area of the polygons. The results are Ok, but I need to "clean" them.

How do I find the shape index, compactness or assymetry with PostgreSQL/PostGIS? I need a solution for vector data only.

Comment: GIS SE uses a "Focused question / Best answer" model. This question seeks to start a discussion and compile a list of options. Such a request would be appropriate in the [chat] feature, but not here in the main site.

Comment: Well roads and rivers have colours too, so if you have that information, it would help. From my experience working with land parcels, there is no typical land shape type. You are likely to get much better results if you can add in additional remote sensed data, as land parcels have a tendency to change over the year as things grow/die. However, as it stands the question is probably too vague for this format, and many Postgis users will not have used eCognition.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. Yes, remote sensing data could help in for such problems, but rasters are not suitable for this project (talking about multimillion data and processing times + storage).

Comment: Hi Mazinga, multi million isn't really that big these days, and even if it were billions, there are cloud solutions for this kind of analysis. If you want to automatically extract land parcels from millions of objects with a high degree of accuracy then you should use as much information as possible. If you are prepared to accept a lower accuracy, please edit the question to make this clear. Have you thought of using something like Google Earth Engine to help with the analysis?

Comment: I want to extract road/river/thin and linear-like polygons and clean the results after extracting those. There is no need to extract all of the mentioned polygons. I already cleaned around 90% of them and would like to push it a little bit further with involving the mentioned parameters. So the question remains: shape index, compactness or asymmetry for vector data in Pg/PostGIS . The accuracy and the environment are part of other topics that would make this question too broad again. No other data must be involved. I process it via a fast server.

Comment: I edited the last reply too much times so I continue here :) The restrictions about the data I can use are connected with the nature of the job and this is just a little part of the database queries. In the end, for me it's important to extract linear polygons and not compact ones, cause in further queries they make problems. @John, thanks for your interests in helping.

Comment: OK, that is reasonable. One possibility would be to use something like [rotating calipers](https://geidav.wordpress.com/tag/rotating-calipers/) to find the minimum oriented bounding box, and then take the ratio of width to height. It is a crude measure, but it might give you an indication of long/thin polygons, ie, more likely to be roads, rivers. I don't think you can do it without the oriented part, as obviously a road going in a diagonal direction could have equal width and height of bounding box.

Comment: I am not aware of a Postgis implementation of this algorithm, though the pseudo code isn't that complex, so it could be created. The run time might not be very quick. I am sure other heuristics could be applied, but, I am really guessing as I only know about Spanish and UK field parcels, and I would give a completely different answer if you were looking at, say, the US mid West.

Comment: Finding the ratios between oriented bounding boxes would be a good index  to check, but I don't know how to implement this. Will try and post it if I manage to get some good results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66238/discussion-between-mazinga-and-john-powell-aka-barca).